# I am not getting notified about comments on my posts any more

Tags: bug, notifications

For example: [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89377/when-is-rapid-fire-better-than-regular-fire/89384#comment123294_89384).

I can give as many other examples as there have been comments on my posts today.

I never got an inbox notification that a comment was left on my post.

I can *see* them in my inbox if I actively go looking for them, but it's not popping up the useful red counter to show me that I have them.

EDIT: I believe I have determined the cause of this. I left one browser window open with the notifications window expanded all day, and then other browser windows were not notified of new inbox messages due to that.

Comment: How about on meta? (test)

Comment: Perhaps it's because he's replying to somebody else (this behaviour would be new though... to test it, somebody reply to me)

Comment: @JQAn Nope. I didn't get notifications for either of those two comments.

Comment: I did get it for your reply

Comment: @JQAn Because he used, "@JQAn"

Comment: @RavenDreamer I got notified for that one...

Comment: Maybe only comments that don't use an @-someone?

Comment: @RavenDreamer you used "@JQAn" to tell me he used "@JQAn" so that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: THIS IS A COMMENT